# Primefaces confirm dialog retains its background opacity after it is dismissed

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Someone who have used Primefaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT may have noticed the following warning.

> The appendToBody attribute of the ConfirmDialog will be deprecated in
>   future versions. Please use appendTo="@(body)" now

Along with Primefaces 4.0 RC1, I have this piece of code.

```
<h:body>
    <h:form prependId="true" id="form">

        <p:confirmDialog id="confirmDialog" 
                         widgetVar="confirmDeleteMultiple" 
                         message="Message" 
                         showEffect="true" 
                         hideEffect="true" 
                         header="Header" 
                         severity="alert" 
                         closeOnEscape="true" 
                         appendTo="@(body)"        <-----------------
                         closable="true">

            <p:commandButton id="btnYes" 
                             value="Yes" 
                             process="@this" 
                             oncomplete="confirmDeleteMultiple.hide()"/>

            <p:commandButton id="btnNo" 
                             value="No" 
                             onclick="confirmDeleteMultiple.hide()" 
                             type="button" />
        </p:confirmDialog>

        <p:commandButton oncomplete="confirmDeleteMultiple.show()" 
                         update=":form:confirmDialog" 
                         actionListener="#{testManagedBean.insert}"
                         ajax="true" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

When the only command button on the page is clicked, the dialog appears with the two buttons given.

On pressing any of these buttons, the dialog disappears but leaving the background opacity. The background opacity loses only when the page is reloaded.

Why does this happen with this new version? Any suggestion? In earlier versions, this was just fine.

Comment: Please report any issues with snapshot/beta/alpha versions directly to software vendor.

Comment: It is associated with `showEffet` and `hideEffect` attributes of confirm dialog - from [PrimeFaces Forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=33884#p108105). It requires something like `showEffect="slide"`, `hideEffect="slide"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is associated with `showEffet` and `hideEffect` attributes of confirm dialog - from [PrimeFaces Forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=33884#p108105).

> There is a misuse of effect attributes, "true" is not a valid value,
>   should be bounce, fade ... 4.x is more strict about wrong attribute
>   values